# How to add SGML end tags?

Tags: vim, sed, sgml

I have an SGML file that looks has lots of `<p>` paragraphs that have implied end tags, like this:

```
<p>Here is one paragraph. 
<p>And here is another. This one contains <i>italics</i>.
<p>Finally, here is another paragraph.
```

There are no end tags on these paragraphs. I want to make it look like this:

```
<p>Here is one paragraph.</p> 
<p>And here is another. This one contains <i>italics</i>.</p>
<p>Finally, here is another paragraph.</p>
```

Is there an easy way to do that using OSS tools? (Like vim, sed, etc?)

Comment: do nothing, it'll look the same

Comment: Good catch. Copy-paste error. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vim, given the imput you've specified you can use `:%s/$/<\/p>/`.
Note that this only works for your example where every paragraph is one line.

In case of multi-line paragraphs, first join all lines `:%j`, then prepend an end tag to the begin tag `:%s/ \+<p>/<\/p><p>/`, then add the final end tag `:%s/$/<\/p>/`. Finally reflow the text with `gqap`.

Answer (score 0):

`%s/<p>\zs\(.*\)/\1<\/p>/` should work in Vim, but the "classic" solution is to `%s/<p>/<\/p><p>/` and then move the first `</p>` to the end of the text.